# What's the difference between `if var in` and `if var contains`?

Tags: comparison, autohotkey

The [AutoHotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm) lists two methods of comparing a variable to items in a list.

> if *Var* in *MatchList*
>   if *Var* contains *MatchList*

What's the difference between `if var in` and `if var contains`?

Comment: Per the documentation you pointed to: *The name of the variable whose contents will be checked. For the "in" operator, an exact match with one of the list items is required. For the "contains" operator, a match occurs more easily: whenever `Var` *contains* one of the list items as a substring.* So `Var` *in* `MatchList` is true only if `Var` is an exact match to a member of `MatchList`. For `Var` *contains* `MatchList` to be true, an element of `MatchList` is a *substring* of `Var`. Note in their examples, `if var contains 1,3` compares 1 and 3 *as strings*. So if `var` is `23`, it is true.

Comment: suppose v=abcd. `v in bc,xy` fails, while `v contains bc,xy` passes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully some examples will help demonstrate the difference.

Example of `if var in MatchList`:

**Match:**

```
F3::
example := "pizza" ; Contains a matching string.
if example in This,is,a,tasty,pizza
    MsgBox, %example% found in MatchList
```

**Negative match:**

```
F3::
example := "pizz" ; Contains no matching string.
if example not in This,is,a,tasty,pizza
    MsgBox, %example% not found in MatchList
```

Example of `if var contains MatchList`:

**Match:**

```
F3::
example := "ice" ; Contains a matching "i" substring.
if example contains p,i,z,z,a
    MsgBox, %example% contains MatchList item(s)
```

**Negative match:**

```
F3::
example := "doggy" ; Contains no matching substring.
if example not contains p,i,z,z,a
    MsgBox, %example% does not contain MatchList item(s)
```